# Как найти маркер на Google maps по id и активировать его InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api

На Google Maps нанесены маркеры, которые были импортированы из json файла. Есть кнопки, кликая по которым происходит перемещение окна и открытия infowindow маркера, определенного по id, который совпадает с id кнопки с класса "selector".

```html
 <script>
 var map;
 var markers=[];
function initMap() {
self = this;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://stripy.by/vendors/schools_by.geojsonp';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  
  window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
 var place = results.features[i].properties.place;
    var coords = results.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
 var id = results.features[i].properties.ids;
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Нажмите чтобы приблизить',
   description : place,
   id : id,
    });
 markers[i] = {
  position: latLng,
  description: place,
  id: id,
 }
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
 map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
 infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + this.description +'</strong><br></div>');
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
  }
}


console.log(markers[1[1]]);
}
    </script>
```

```css
#map {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
       }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<button class="selector" id="1">Маркер 1</button>
<button class="selector" id="2">Маркер 2</button>
<button class="selector" id="3">Маркер 3</button>
```

Получаю ошибку: *Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined*
Помогите победить ошибку.

Comment: если у вас `markers` в коде упоминается лишь единожды, и это не при определении этой переменной, то чего вы еще хотите от браузера? Переменную объявите `var markers = {};` в начале и маркеры туда занесите `markers[id] = marker;` при их создании, потом уж используйте-то?

Comment: Согласен, исправил, но в массив ничего не добавляется. Гляньте пожалуйста что не так .

Comment: дак а почему вы добавляете не `marker`, а какой-то объект? зы: у вас в `log` какая-то ерунда написана

Comment: Пробовал, но объекты с одинаковыми названиями добавить не получается...